# Packing some macports libraries with executable file to create app bundle

Tags: macos, shared-libraries, bundle, macports

I'm trying to create an application bundle for a game that uses some libraries I installed using macports. I would like to put the dependencies inside the bundle but am at loss on how to do that.

I've compiled the game and tried to use install_name_tool to change the path used so that the executable searches inside the bundle, I get no error but the path doesn't change. E.g.:
    install_name_tool -change libSDL-1.2.0.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib meandmyshadow

The executable was built using a CMake generated Makefile.

Would XCode be a better option? Is there anything I'm missing from the steps I'm taking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question about how to use `install_name_tool`: if you look at the library linkage of meandmyshadow using `otool -L meandmyshadow` it'll probably look something like this:

```
meandmyshadow:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.11)
    /opt/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib (compatibility version 12.0.0, current version 12.3.0)
    ...
```

When you use `install_name_tool` to change a reference in the program, you need to use the complete reference. You specified that you wanted to change the reference `libSDL-1.2.0.dylib` but you need to specify the absolute path, e.g. `/opt/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib`:

```
install_name_tool -change /opt/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib meandmyshadow
```

As for the bigger question about how to include libraries into an application bundle, you can do it manually as you're doing above with `install_name_tool`, or consider trying [dylibbundler](http://macdylibbundler.sourceforge.net/) which does it for you automatically. You can install it using MacPorts: `sudo port install dylibbundler`.